# CMake multi-config generators use wrong build directory

Tags: cmake, build, msbuild

I have a problem related to multi-config generators in CMake.
The task is simple: I just want to copy some files(glsl shaders) into runtime directory(for executable to read in runtime).

I have following target hierarchy: I have **library**(DLL) target and **executable, that will be created by user**. Library is then linked with executable. And here's the problem.
I used following code:

```
configure_file("${SHADER_SRC}" "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIR}/shaders/${SHADER_OUTPUT_FILENAME}" COPYONLY)
```

It produces build tree similar to that:

- Binary dir

  - BUILD_TYPE(For example, debug)

    - bin

      - shaders

        - My Files are here. Works fine
      - Other targets

It works fine with single-config generators.
But when I start using `Visual Studio 16 2019` multi-config generator, following happens:

- Binary dir

  - BUILD_TYPE

    - bin

      - shaders

        - My Files are here. Works fine
      - BUILD_TYPE

        - Other targets
          Shaders are no longer seen by executable because they are in wrong directory.
          How can this problem be solved?

P.S.
I used `add_custom_command` version too:

```
set(SHADER_OUTPUT_FILENAME "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/shaders/${SHADER_FILENAME}")
    
add_custom_command(
            TARGET ${LIBRARY_TARGET_NAME} PRE_BUILD
            WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
            COMMENT "Copying shader (${SHADER_FILENAME}) to build directory..."
            BYPRODUCTS "${SHADER_OUTPUT_FILENAME}"

            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                    ${SHADER_SRC} # Shader file in source directory
                    ${SHADER_OUTPUT_FILENAME} # Shader file that I need in build directory

            VERBATIM
    )
```

Comment: Please create a [mre], i.e. a complete minimal `CmakeLists.txt` that can be used to reproduce the problem together with the required (minimal) input files.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(UNIX)
  set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
  set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
  # for multi-config build system (e.g. xcode, ninja-multiconfig)
  foreach(OUTPUTCONFIG IN LISTS CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
    string(TOUPPER ${OUTPUTCONFIG} OUTPUTCONFIG)
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
  endforeach()
else()
  set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
  set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
  # for multi-config builds (e.g. msvc)
  foreach(OUTPUTCONFIG IN LISTS CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
    string(TOUPPER ${OUTPUTCONFIG} OUTPUTCONFIG)
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
  endforeach()
endif()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without this "ifs"?